# Searching an int64 date in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I have a MongoDB that has a field as int64 but it is actually a date. I can't change the DB. Not mine but need to query it by date. I just don't know how to say the following query to get the records I want because of this column. Can anyone help me understand it? I have looked in the docs but can't find what to do here.

```
db.getCollection('logs').find({   
 entrytimestamp: { $gte: ISODate("2023-08-09T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte: ISODate("2023-08-09T23:59:59.000Z") }
}).count()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked out [$toDate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/rapid/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/)?